# String to function with parameters

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to Python, but I have a lot of experience in languages like C++ and Java. I am trying to parse a string to a function with parameters.
This is what I got so far:

```
def DimLights(percent = 1.0):
    print 'Dimming lights to ' + "{:.2f}".format(percent * 100) + ' percent'

def TurnOffLights():
    print 'Turning off lights'

function_mappings = {'DimLights': DimLights,
                     'TurnOffLights': TurnOffLights}

def select_function():
    while True:
        try:
            return function_mappings[raw_input('Please input the function you want to use')]
        except:
            print 'Invalid function, try again.'

while True:
    function = select_function()
    function()
```

It's working as long as I don't use any parameters, but I can't think of a solution that would work with parameters.
Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Comment: So you want to pass an argument into `select_function()` that would be in turn passed into the function you select?

Comment: unsolicited tip: please never leave an `except:` to catch all errors.  You probably want `KeyError` and some select others here.  But you probably don't want `SyntaxError` et al.

Comment: @APerson: But what if I have more than one argument?
Brian Cain: Thanks, I'll do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this , Not a complete answer.But You can use it:

```
def DimLights(percent = 1.0):
    print 'Dimming lights to ' + "{:.2f}".format(percent * 100) + ' percent'

def TurnOffLights():
    print 'Turning off lights'

function_mappings = {'DimLights': DimLights,
                     'TurnOffLights': TurnOffLights}

def select_function():
    while True:
        try:
            inp = raw_input('Please input the function you want to use:')
            inp = inp.split()
            return function_mappings[inp[0]], inp[1]
        except:
            print 'Invalid function, try again.'
            break

function, arg = select_function()
function(float(arg))
# while True:
#     function = select_function
#     function()

>>>Please input the function you want to use:DimLights 2.0
Dimming lights to 200.00 percent
```

**Note**

Put space between function and parameter. Also parameter is required.Otherwise `Index error` will occur

Comment: Thank you so much!
This helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with its `maxsplit` argument to strip off just the actual command, and [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) to parse the arguments.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a total noob when it comes to Python. Where exactly would I use str.split()?

Comment: The input is a `str`, so you'd use it right on the input. `inputline = raw_input(...); command, arguments = inputline.split(maxsplit=1)`

Comment: I don't know why I don't get this.
So my input is for example: DimLights(1.0)
Now I want to get rid of the'(1.0)' with inputline..split(maxsplit=1), right?
And how do I parse the arguments.
I feel really dumb right now.

Comment: If you simplify the input to "DimLights 1.0" then you can use this. The parens are just noise unless you're either programming or doing math.

Comment: Hmm
I'm using python 2.7 and it gives me an error:
split() takes no keyword arguments
Is maxsplit a 3.4 feature?